# Rewrite dynamic Magento URL

Tags: nginx, magento-1.4

I have a Magento v1.4.1.1 installation on Nginx web server. I'm trying to rewrite the following dynamic URL:

```
#5028 is the dynamic id passed in the URL
$baseUrl/design/index/index/design_id/5028
```

To:

```
$baseUrl/my/design/5028
```

I have used the Magento's "URL Rewrite Management" to rewrite static URLs, without a problem. But it seems I cannot use dynamic parameters.

I've also tried to do the following on Nginx configuration inside my `server{}` location

```
rewrite ^/my/designs/([0-9]+)$ /design/index/index/design_id/$1 last;
```

But it's not getting catch, I keep getting 404 errors if I try to access `http://mysite.com/my/design/5028`

Another rule right next to this one works perfectly

```
rewrite ^(/fb)/design/([0-9]+)$ $1/landing_no_contest.php?design_id=$2? last;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Magento's "URL Rewrite Managment" does *not* support dynamic links, afaik.

You could programmatically add static rewrites per `design_id` to it, though:

```php
$iStoreId = 1;
$sOptions = 'RP'; // 'RP' for a 301, or 'R' for a 302
$aDesignId = array(5026, 5027, 5028);

foreach ($aDesignId as $iDesignId) {
    Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
        ->setStoreId($iStoreId)
        ->setCategoryId(null)
        ->setProductId(null)
        ->setIdPath(str_replace('0.', '', str_replace(' ', '_', microtime())))
        ->setRequestPath('design/index/index/design_id/' . $iDesignId)
        ->setTargetPath('my/design/' . $iDesignId)
        ->setIsSystem(0)
        ->setOptions($sOptions)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where do I have to add this code? My concern now, is that I have 5k+ designs, then I'll need to create 5k+ static rewrites ?? Do you know if there is a way to register the route using a regular expression, I know all my design_id are integers values.

Comment: I though I was registering this routes everytime it was loading the page, now I see I'm saving it on `core_url_rewrite`, `Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')` Thanks this worked great! So the solution was to register my existing designs once, and then for each new design I create, I add a new static rewrite.